# Getting the source path of a BitmapImage object

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, bitmapimage

I have a Windows 8 project using MVVM, XAML and C#.

One of my methods is currently updating an `ObservableCollection` of all the images in the Pictures folder, converted to `BitmapImage` format, and this is bound to my xaml to display the images in a `ListGrid`. The problem I am having is that I wish to use the `SelectedItem` property in `ListGrid` to allow the user to open the picture that is DoubleTapped - to do this, I need to get at the path of the `BitmapImages` in my `ObservableCollection`. Currently, when I try to do this, the `UriSource` property is set to null. What have I done incorrectly ?

Here is the method populating my ObservableCollection, "Images" :

```
  private async void FindRelatedImages()
        {
            FileOpenPicker picPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
            var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
            StorageFolder folderToGetPicsFrom = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
            var query = folderToGetPicsFrom.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
            // Process results
            ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> newList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
            foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
            {
                // Process file
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage( uriSource : new Uri(file.Path));
               // src.UriSource = new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite));
                newList.Add(src);
            }
            Images = newList;
        }
```

Comment: Simon so what is the issue that you are having can you elaborate a bit more..? if there is an Error please provide the error that you are experiencing

Comment: What about `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` have you looked at that..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE the error is that I need to get the file path of the BitmapImage objects - and I am assuming this is generally stored in the UriSource property of the object - however, for me, this is null. I am assuming I am constructing it incorrectly.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have tried this, however the call to src.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)); seems to reset the UriSource to null again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt setting BitmapImage.UriSource to new Uri(file.Path)) for an arbitrary file is doing anything and by calling SetSource - you are basically overriding that faulty setting. Normally if you set UriSource to a valid source - you don't need to call SetSource afterwards - these are two different methods for loading an image.

Instead of using ObservableCollection you can use something like ObservableCollection where ItemViewModel has a property for the BitmapImage AND the StorageFile. Then you have all you need to pass the path or file elsewhere. Then again - why not just pass the BitmapImage itself on a double tap? If you need the path to open the image as a WriteableBitmap - why not just start with a WriteableBitmap. If you need the path for whatever other reason - you can just add a property to your ItemViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for that; I ended up creating a new Model to represent the data. I thought that it would be possible to get the path from the BitmapImage object...unfortunately it is not! Have it working now by using a new model of a class containing a Uri and a BitmapImage :).

Comment: Do note that your Uri might be invalid though if you are putting StorageFile.Path in there. Perhaps using a string would make more sense.